# Is there a close relative to citrus trees, which can grow in the northeast US?

Tags: fruit-trees, plant-recommendations, citrus, grafting, technique

I am interested in knowing what is a known close relative to citrus, that is known to grow in the northeast US, such as western New York. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: I'm guessing from your choice of tags that you intend to graft them/use them as a rootstock. Note that cold will still affect the scions, if you choose a sweet-fruited citrus scion.

Comment: correct 1 to see if I can 2 for the novelty of having such a tree in the yard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coldest area in western New York gets down to about -25° Fahrenheit, so no true citrus will survive. The closest you'll get is [Trifoliate Orange, *Poncirus trifoliata*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trifoliate_orange). This plant can inter-graft and hybridize with *Citrus* species, but is inedibly bitter. It is an extremely thorny plant. It's leaves are compound and deciduous. It is hardy to -22° Fahrenheit. They can get up to about 25 feet tall in warmer areas, up to 8-10 feet in the coldest parts of it's range.

Comment: Next question is when I get a root stock which way to graft is recommended? I'm not certain to how the graft should be done on this root stock.